# Using summary() and summary.lm() on planned comparisons in R - why do the outputs differ?

Tags: r, comparison, summary, anova

I have run a three-way independent ANOVA in R. (Sound) Manipulation being my independent variable with the three levels: congruent (KON), incongruent (INK) and no sound (control). Furthermore, I have constructed planned comparisons. The first comparison c1 is the contrast of KON & INK vs. the control group and the second comparison c2 is the contrast of KON vs. INK. The outputs look like this:

**summary(model)**

```
                                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Manipulation                              2  11.97   5.985 2.388 0.0975 .
  Manipulation: control vs. Experimental  1   7.97   7.970 3.181 0.0778 .
  Manipulation: INK vs. KON               1   4.00   3.999 1.596 0.2097 
Residuals                                91 228.01   2.506                                           
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**summary.lm(model)**

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5062 -1.3333 -0.3333  1.1398  4.4111 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      3.0317     0.1647  18.411   <2e-16 *** 
Manipulationc1  -0.2214     0.1172  -1.889   0.0621 .  
Manipulationc2  -0.2531     0.2003  -1.263   0.2097    
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.583 on 91 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.04988,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02899 
F-statistic: 2.388 on 2 and 91 DF,  p-value: 0.0975
```

What strikes me is that R uses my pre-defined label of the comparisons, i.e. "control vs. experimental" and "INK vs. KON" in the first summary() output, yet it uses something else in the second output summary.lm(). Why is this?

Furthermore, it seems odd, that the p-value of the first comparison differs across the two outputs, i.e. 0.0778 in case of summary() and 0.0621 in case of summary.lm(). Where is this difference coming from?

Comment: Google "treatment contrasts".

Comment: The second part of your question is not related to R, but is a question for the measures of goodness for the both methods (i.e. it is a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ).

Comment: Thanks jogo. where do I draw a line which posts belongs to stackoverflow and which to stat.exchange? In this case I am curious about particularities of the R program, so I thought it better fits stackoverflow.

Comment: @JensStach Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic with http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect `class(model)`:

```
M <- aov(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
summary(M)
summary.lm(M)
class(M)
```

First there is "aov" - so `summary(M)` is the same as `summary.aov(M)`